# Manipulating data during a MiTM

Tags: penetration-test, man-in-the-middle

I'm trying to learn some attack methods by myself and I have hit a wall where I can't find any information. I have successfully performed an ARP MiTM between 2 systems and I am able to sniff the traffic using tcpdump, driftnet, etc.

My question is: How can I actively modify the packets by injecting HTML code into the response (non SSL, of course)

Comment: I prefer Kali Linux, a few Alfa WiFi external-USB radios, and to `apt-get install mana-toolkit mitmf'. These last two tools provide a lot more than the MITM-focused tools I've seen in 2014 or earlier

Answer (score 1):

[Ettercap](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/ettercapfilter) has options to inject into an html stream. You could also use proxies.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically using [Ettercap](http://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/), you want to implement filters. You can write your own filters to identify specific types of traffic and replace it with your own data. Here is a SANS reading room [paper](http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/tools/ettercap-primer-1406) that goes into a lot of detail about Ettercap, or you can just Google for "ettercap filters" and read up on it more.